# 'for loop' python 3 dictionaries inside dictionaries from .plist (or xml)

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Hopefully a quick python question here...

```
import plistlib

pl = plistlib.readPlist('/Users/name/Documents/some.plist')

print(pl[0]['keyA'] , pl[0]['keyD'] , pl[0]['keyG'])
```

how would I write a for loop or a list function that would cycle through a dictionary printing the values to certain keys.

The main dictionary will have say 30 entries (dictionaries in the dictionary) with each one having about 40 keys within.)

Example:

```
print(pl[0]['keyA'] , pl[0]['keyD'] , pl[0]['keyG'])
print(pl[1]['keyA'] , pl[1]['keyD'] , pl[1]['keyG'])
print(pl[2]['keyA'] , pl[2]['keyD'] , pl[2]['keyG'])
print(pl[n]['keyA'] , pl[n]['keyD'] , pl[n]['keyG'])
```

where `pl` is the main dictionary and then `0 - n` refer to the dictionaries within the dictionary.

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write it! :p

```
for sub_dict in pl.values():
    print sub_dict['keyA'], sub_dict['keyD'], sub_dict['keyG']
```

(`.values()` says to iterate over the values of the dictionary, since normally iterating over a dictionary goes through its keys. In Python 2 use `.itervalues()` instead.)

Comment: `File "plistread.py", line 6
    print sub_dict['NOISE'], sub_dict['SSID_STR'], sub_dict['BSSID']
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plistread.py", line 5, in <module>
    for sub_dict in pl.values():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
`

Comment: If it says `'list' object has no attribute 'values'` then the `'list'` object has no `'values'` attribute! The problem is that the outer data structure is a list not a dictionary. To iterate over lists, you can just write `for sub_dict in pl:`.

Comment: @user969617 You are using Python 3, so you have to use `print` as a function of course.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem has nothing to do with `plist`, it's with a nested dictionary.

From what you wrote it seems that your `pl` dict looks like:

```
pl = {0: {'keyA': 1, 'keyD': 2, 'keyG': 3}, 
      1: {'keyA': 11, 'keyD': 12, 'keyG': 13}}
```

In that case simply use:

```
keys = ['keyA', 'keyD', 'keyG']
for i in range(len(pl)):
    print(' '.join(str(pl[i][key]) for key in keys)
```

This will work if *all* your `pl` keys are numbers, otherwise you may want to use [`.items()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) or [`.values()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values), take a look at the [official dict documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)